# Getting a NullPointerException when I make a == comparison with null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm having difficulty with a current program. When I try and check whether the node (an object) is null I get a NullPointerException which I though you were allowed to do. I'm getting the exception in this if statement

```
        else if(direction == 0) {
            cursor = cursor.getParent();
            if(cursor.getRight() != null)
                direction = 1;
            else
                direction = 0;
        }
```

I get the exception on the third line 'if(cursor.getRight() != null)' which I've tried multiple ways to write it and still get the same exception. ('if(null != cursor.getRight)' and 'if(!(null == cursor.getRight())'
The getRight() method returns the instance of the next node (object) and is initialized to null when that object is initialized.

Comment: `cursor.getParent();` is probably returning null hence NPE.

Comment: Well, what happens if a `cursor` has not parent (i.e. is the "higest" cursor (if you like to name it that way))? Then `cursor` is `null` and `cursor.getRight()` will cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My `cursor.getParent()` was returning null because the parents of each node weren't being set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if(direction == 0) {
            cursor = cursor.getParent();
            if(cursor.getRight() != null)
                direction = 1;
            else
                direction = 0;
        }
```

The reason you get a `NullPointerException` is because `cursor` is set to `null`, hence when you try `cursor.getRight()`, it evaluates to `null.getRight()` hence the exception.

I suggest you to try following code:

```
else if(direction == 0) {
            cursor = cursor.getParent();
            if(cursor!=null && cursor.getRight() != null)
                direction = 1;
            else
                direction = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll probably find that "cursor.getParent()" returns null, thus setting "cursor" to null on the 2nd line.  Then when the third line attempts to call "getRight()" on a null object, you get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is likely being set to null on the second line getParent and then you are trying to access methods of a null element. First check to make sure cursor is not null before you check if cursor.getRight() is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(direction == 0) {
    cursor = cursor.getParent();
    if(cursor != null && cursor.getRight() != null)
        direction = 1;
    else
        direction = 0;
}
```